# Request part of array of objects through api call

Tags: angular

```json
{
  response:{
    "users":[
      {
        name: user1,
        category: 'science',
        title: 'Loreum ispum',
        body: 'dummy text',
        videos:['url1','url2'] 
      },
      {
        name: user2,
        category: 'civil',
        title: 'Loreum ispum',
        body: 'dummy text', 
        videos:['url1','url2']
      },
      {   
        name: user3,
        category: 'maths',
        title: 'Loreum ispum',
        body: 'dummy text',
        videos:['url1','url2',''url3'] 
      }
    ],
    "categories":[
      'science',
      'maths',
      'social',
      'english',
      'cs',
      'mech',
      'civil'
    ],
  }
}
```

I want to call users and categories separately because it has large amount of data. It takes too much time to get a response from server. So I just want to split array of objects into individual in api call.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Not if you have no access to the code of the API. But really a laaarge data don't makes takes too time (think about typical download speed of an ADSL are 300 Mbps).

If you only need part of the call your can use pipe(map) to transform the response

```
getData(){
  return this.httpClient.get(..yourURL...).pipe(
       map((res:any)=>({users:res.users,categories:res.categories})
  )
}
```

Or, e.g. if you want

```
getData(){
  return this.httpClient.get(..yourURL...).pipe(
       map((res:any)=>{
        const categories=res.categories.map((x,i)=>({id:i,category:x})
        const user=res.users.map(x=>{
           cont cat=categories.first(c=>c.category==x.category)
           return {name:x.name,category:cat?.id}
        })
        return {users:users,categories:categories}
  )
}
```